# What the reason of "font" and "content" overwriting in Eric Meyer's reset.css?

Tags: css, cross-browser

[Original CSS rules](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html) written by Eric Meyer:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Here are two overwritings:

1. `font: inherit;` overwrites `font-size: 100%;`
2. `content: none` overwrites `content: ''`.

In the moders IDE with code quality control tools, below warnings will be annoy:

[image]

[image]

What the reason of this overwritings?

I suppose we may below corrections:

- Currently Internet Explorer 7 does not supported anywhere. So, the `font: inherit;` will be enough without `font-size: 100%`;
- Value `''` for `content` property supported everywhere where `:after` and `:before` supported. So, we don't need `content: none`.

Comment: the date of the version is 2011 so we need to consider browser support 7 years later and I think IE was still alive

Comment: @Temani Afif, IE8 and later understands `font: inherit;`, is not it?

Comment: I am not the IE expert but you need to verify ... I don't know what was the web state in 2011